# How to match/split a token from a string that has a sentence so that it does not consider the space in the beginning

Tags: java, string, split

> ```
>        YES      leading spaces        are valid,    problemsetters are         evillllll
> ```

is my input, and the expected output is:

> 8
>
> YES
>
> leading
>
> spaces
>
> are
>
> valid
>
> problemsetters
>
> are
>
> evillllll
>
> {-truncated-}

below is my program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String array[] = new String[25];
        array = s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        System.out.println(array.length);
        for (String temp: array)
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

The output that I'm receiving on the console is:

> 9
>
> YES
>
> leading
>
> spaces
>
> are
>
> valid
>
> problemsetters
>
> are
>
> evillllll

error here is that the 1st element of the array is taking up a space which is causing the number of tokens to be equal to 9 instead of 8 which must not be the case, the above code works perfectly fine for some string that doesn't begin with space.

Any idea to help me in getting the 1st space ignored will help.

Comment: I've also tried using array=input.split("[ ,?!]+"); , to split the string ,still no go. also not sure why \s must be read as white space(space , tab new line ) but not sure why compiler throws : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Have you tried using [String#trim()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-trim-method-example/) to get rid of the leading space(s)?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ --- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: @Pain_Nr `\s` throws error because in strings `\s` have no special meaning like`\n`, so you must escape backslash: `\\s` > \\ will be evaluates to \

Comment: thank you so very much for responding. Actually the below trim() idea did the trick and i'll try \\s as well but just wanted to highlight one more thing here. when i use String[] array = s.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+"); on an input which is like String s="         ", upon printing it post trimming i can see that there is nothing in side it but when i use String[] array = s.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+"); i can see that the size of the array is 1, but ideally speaking the number of string tokens must be zero if the input string has only spaces and no alphabets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just trim the string before you split

**trim**

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

```
String[] array = s.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
```

The problem is not with `trim` somehow regex is splitting empty string into String[] of size `1`

**Case 1:**

```
    String str=" ";  //blank string
    System.out.println(str.split("[^a-zA-Z]+").length); //0
```

**Case 2:**

```
    String str=""; //empty string 
    System.out.println(str.split("[^a-zA-Z]+").length); //1
```

**trim operation on empty or blank string returns empty string always**

**Case 3:**

```
    String str="";  //empty
    String str1 = " ";  //blank
    System.out.println(str.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+").length); //1
    System.out.println(str1.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+").length); //1
```

**To avoid this**

> trim always input string then check `isEmpty()` will return true if string is empty (false on blank string) and then do the split function

```
System.out.println(" ".isEmpty()+"----"+"".isEmpty()); //false----true
```

Comment: thank you so very much for responding. Actually the below trim() idea did the trick and i'll try \\s as well but just wanted to highlight one more thing here. when i use String[] array = s.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+"); on an input which is like String s="         ", upon printing it post trimming i can see that there is nothing in side it but when i use String[] array = s.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+"); i can see that the size of the array is 1, but ideally speaking the number of string tokens must be zero if the input string has only spaces and no alphabets

Comment: may be that my regex needs to have a better condition!?

Comment: I believe that is regex problem, let me try

Comment: public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String trimmed=s.trim();
        if(trimmed.isEmpty()==true)
        {
            System.out.println(trimmed.length());
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        else
        {
        String [] array= trimmed.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        System.out.println(array.length);
        for (String temp: array)
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        scan.close();
        }
    }
}

Comment: the above code did the trick , thank you @Deadpool. thanks a bunch . and just to add https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-string-tokens/problem was the query. thanks again for saving the WORLD.

Comment: yup always   @MohammedNadeem

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Java 9, you can use the [`Scanner.tokens`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#tokens()) method, which returns a `Stream<String>` that consists only of, well, tokens, thus ignoring all whitespaces:

```
String str = "       YES      leading spaces        are valid,    problemsetters are         evillllll ";
String[] array = new Scanner(str)
        .useDelimiter("[,\\s]+")
        .tokens()
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

This code produces your expected output. The only caveat is to use both spaces and the comma as delimiters.

Comment: let me try Mate and thank you for your kind response

Comment: just to heads up, will return the same result for empty string